# two sql query mix for one

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I want to combine two pieces of code into one, but I'm getting an error:

Part 1

```
SELECT idstd,namestd, idmajor, 
      c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, 
      c7, c8, c9, c10,c11,c12,
      c13,c14,c15 
FROM 
    (SELECT status, idstd,namestd, idmajor, 
           'C' + cast(row_number() 
            OVER (partition BY idstd, idmajor 
               ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS varchar(10)) col
     FROM tbcheked) src 
PIVOT (MAX(status) FOR col IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, 
                               C6, C7, C8, C9, C10,
                               c11,c12,c13,c14,c15)) piv
```

This code is for checking if the column `status` has values of `present`, `absent` or `leave`.

Example:

```
id    |   c1      |   c2     |     c3  |     c4  |     c5  |
1        present     absent    present   leave     present
```

I have the second piece of code for status count:

```
    SELECT idstd, 
           namemajor, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'present' 
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
               END) AS present, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'absent' 
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
               END) AS absent, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'leave' 
                    THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END) AS leave, 
   FROM tbcheked GROUP BY idstd, namemajor 
   ORDER BY idstd
```

Output:

```
id     | present  |  absent  |  leave  |
1          3           1          1
```

Now, I want to join both queries:

```
id    |   c1      |   c2     |     c3  |     c4  |     c5  |  present  |  absent  |  leave  |
1        present     absent    present   leave     present     3            1         1
```

Comment: Protip: If you have column names ending in `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. You're doing it wrong and need to [normalize your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 1):

Use [**join**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for conbining the output of both the queries.

```
select a.*, b.*
from (query 1)a join (query 2)b on a.id=b.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat each part as a sub-query and join them:

```
select
    <whatever>
from
        (
            SELECT idstd,namestd, idmajor, 
                  c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, 
                  c7, c8, c9, c10,c11,c12,
                  c13,c14,c15 
            FROM 
                (SELECT status, idstd,namestd, idmajor, 
                       'C' + cast(row_number() 
                        OVER (partition BY idstd, idmajor 
                           ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS varchar(10)) col
                 FROM tbcheked) src 
            PIVOT (MAX(status) FOR col IN (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, 
                                           C6, C7, C8, C9, C10,
                                           c11,c12,c13,c14,c15)) piv
        ) as PivotedBit
INNER JOIN -- or OUTER, depending on your requirement
        (
            SELECT idstd, 
                   namemajor, 
                   SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'present' 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                       END) AS present, 
                   SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'absent' 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                       END) AS absent, 
                   SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'leave' 
                            THEN 1 
                            ELSE 0 
                        END) AS leave, 
            FROM tbcheked GROUP BY idstd, namemajor 
            --ORDER BY idstd -- cannot have this in a sub-query
        ) as SummingBit
    on SummingBit.idstd = PivotedBit.idstd
    -- and any other common keys
    ORDER BY idstd
```

It'll do two complete scans of `tbcheked`, so it won't be fast.

I have a hunch that adding dummy columns to the inner select of the `PIVOT` query using the `CASE` statements from the summing query, then adding `SUM()` to the `PIVOT` clause would be better.  I haven't thought this through fully, however.